# mysql_fetch_object with specific class

Tags: php, mysql, database, class

I developed an object-oriented guestbook and I have my Class `GuestBookEntry`:

```
class GuestBookEntry {
protected $id;
protected $entryDate;
protected $authorName;
protected $authorMail;  
protected $entryText; 

// getters, setters and specific functions are omitted
}
```

I also have a `mysql` table with the same names as columns.

Well, when I fetch guestbook entries, it seems to work, but it only displays the `ID` and the `Date`, which where returned by getters. The other things won't return to the template.

The code looks like this:

```
public function showEntries() { 
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM dng_entries ORDER BY id DESC');     
    while($entry = @mysql_fetch_object($query, 'GuestBookEntry')) {
        if(empty($entry)) {
        echo '<font color="white">Keine Eintr&auml;ge vorhanden...</font>';
        } else {    
        var_dump($entry);
        echo '<table class="table table-bordered entryfield" align="right">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowspan="2">'.$entry->getId().'</td>
                        <td width="20%">Datum:</td>
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>'.$entry->getEntryDate().'</td>
                        <td>'.$entry->getAuthorName().'</td>
                        <td><a href="mailto:'.$entry->getAuthorMail().'">'.$entry->getAuthorMail().'</a></td>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td width="10%" valign="middle">Eintrag:</td>
                    <th colspan="3" valign="top" height="100px">'.$entry->getEntryText().'</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>';
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a `var_dump` of e.g. object:

```
object(GuestBookEntry)#2 (5) { ["id":protected]=> string(1) "2" ["entryDate":protected]=> int(1344696811) ["authorName":protected]=> NULL ["authorMail":protected]=> NULL ["entryText":protected]=> NULL }
```

update: well here is the rest of GuestBookEntry class:

```
public function __construct($authorName, $authorMail, $entryText) {
       $this->authorName    = $authorName;
       $this->authorMail    = $authorMail;
       $this->entryDate     = time();
       $this->entryText     = $entryText;
    }

    public function getId() {
       return $this->id;
    }
    public function getAuthorName() {
       return (String) $this->authorName;
    }
    public function getAuthorMail() {
       return (String) $this->authorMail;
    }
    public function getEntryDate() {
       return date('d.n.Y', $this->entryDate);
    }
    public function getEntryText() {
       return $this->entryText;
    }

    public function setAuthorName($authorName) {
       $this->authorName=$authorName;
    }   
    public function setAuthorMail($authorMail) {
       $this->authorMail=$authorMail;
    }
    public function setEntryDate($entryDate) {
       $this->entryDate=$entryDate;
    }
    public function setEntryText($entryText) {
       $this->entryText=$entryText;
    }
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers). And don't use the `@` operator. There might be something funny going on in your `guestBookEntry` class getters/setters, show their code.

Comment: The `var_dump()` output you include shows that some of your attributes, e.g. `authorName` are `NULL`. Have you checked the data the query is returning?

Comment: What the heck is `mysql_fetch_object`.
Don't use it.

Comment: Please add your db create statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is case sensitivity. MySQL column names don't deal with camel case, but PHP see's a difference between properties based on case such as $entryDate and $entrydate.   Stick to lowercase with underscores if you need visual seperation.   The reason why `id` works is it's all lower case.

I think if you simply lowercase all your property names that are supposed map to table columns everything will work.

BTW... The camel case issue with column names may vary based on the OS running the sql server.